# How to execute change directory and execute two programs in parallel in a single shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have two commands, that both change directories and runs a program. I'd like to combine them into a single shell script.

The commands are:

```
cd engine && python cli.py run-engine
cd javascript/services/client && yarn watch
```

How can I combine them into a single shell script?

Comment: wrap lines in `pushd ... popd` or `( ... )`

Comment: I tried `(cd engine && python cli.py run-engine; cd javascript/services/client && yarn watch)` but to no avail.

Comment: you would wrap each line separately

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "combine them into a single shell script"? The highlighted code in your question essentially constitutes a single shell script with the possible exception of the first line being a shebang `#!/bin/bash` and marking the file as executable `chmod +x scriptname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start your commands with &

```
#! /bin/sh

cd engine && python cli.py run-engine &
cd javascript/services/client && yarn watch &
```

If you need to synchronize with them, you can add two "wait".  It will only finish when the longest lived process has finished.

Or your can just use the ampersand with the first one and then run the second one without backgrounding it.

Or you can use something like the tool "daemon" (apt install daemon) to control the service start/stop.

Comment: Can there be race condition on cd? Because both are running in parallel

Comment: @tejasvi88: No, because each series of commands separated by "&&" and ending with a "&" is executed in series in a separate subshell. Each [sub]shell will have its own current working directory.